# PHP SQL Wrapper

Tags: php, sql, wrapper

Anyone have suggestions on wrappers for SQL within PHP?  I've been using ezSQL, which is awesome, but wanted to see if anyone had any other suggestions.

Comment: If ezSQL is awesome, why are you looking for a new wrapper? What additional features do you want?

Comment: I don't know that I want any additional features.  I'm just testing the water for something different/better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), if you want full blown ORM. [Zend_DB_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) is fine if all you need is a query builder.

Comment: As long as your building with APC support and perhaps have memcache, the extensive feature list of Doctrine easily balances out its footprint.

Answer (score 3):

[PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo)

Comment: That's not really a wrapper for SQL. Just handles database communication, you'll still have to write the SQL queries.

Comment: With ezSql you also have to write the SQL yourself.  Wrapper might be a good name?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) DB backage, it has adapters for most database connectivity (PDO, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Sqlite), is object oriented and uses row gateway and table gateway patterns, prevents SQL injections, works with stored procedures, has a builtin profiler etc.
but If you want some ORM solution, I suggest [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/), or [Doctorine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You could always look into an ORM solution like [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/).